# Using Named Entity Extraction in solr 7.3

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am trying to use NER in Solr(SolrCloud) 7.3 but I am a little bit missing some documentation.

**What I have found:**

https://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_3_0//solr-analysis-extras/org/apache/solr/update/processor/OpenNLPExtractNamedEntitiesUpdateProcessorFactory.html

**What I have done:**

*Parts of solrconfig.xml*

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="multiple-extract">
   <processor class="solr.OpenNLPExtractNamedEntitiesUpdateProcessorFactory">
     <str name="modelFile">opennlp/en-ner-person.bin</str>
     <str name="analyzerFieldType">text_opennlp</str>
     <str name="source">description_en</str>
     <str name="dest">content</str>
   </processor>
   <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
   <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
 </updateRequestProcessorChain>



    <requestHandler name="/myupdate " class="solr.UpdateRequestHandler">
      <lst name="defaults">
        <str name="update.chain">multiple-extract</str>
      </lst>
    </requestHandler>
```

*Parts of management schema*

```
 <field name="_root_" type="string" docValues="false" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <field name="_text_" type="text_general" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="false"/>
  <field name="_version_" type="plong" indexed="false" stored="false"/>
  <field name="content" type="text_opennlp" indexed="true" termOffsets="true" stored="true" termPayloads="true" termPositions="true" docValues="false" termVectors="true" multiValued="true" required="true"/>
  <field name="content_pos" type="text_opennlp_pos" indexed="true" termOffsets="true" stored="true" termPayloads="true" termPositions="true" docValues="false" termVectors="true" multiValued="true" required="true"/>
  <field name="description_en" type="text_en" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
  <field name="id" type="string" multiValued="false" indexed="true" required="true" stored="true"/>

<fieldType name="text_opennlp" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.OpenNLPTokenizerFactory" tokenizerModel="opennlp/en-token.bin" sentenceModel="opennlp/en-sent.bin"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
  <fieldType name="text_opennlp_pos" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
      <tokenizer class="solr.OpenNLPTokenizerFactory" tokenizerModel="opennlp/en-token.bin" sentenceModel="opennlp/en-sent.bin"/>
      <filter class="solr.OpenNLPPOSFilterFactory" posTaggerModel="opennlp/en-pos-maxent.bin"/>
      <filter class="solr.TypeAsPayloadFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
  </fieldType>
```

**My assumption**

As I assume when I will send data using multiple-extract update processor chain it will be extracted form  `<str name="source">description_en</str>` and put to 
`<str name="dest">content</str>`. But I don't even see this behavior.

**My tests**

*request for data insert*

`POST http://localhost:8983/solr/numberplate/update?version=2.2&wt=xml&update.chain=multiple-extract`

```
<add><doc><field name="id">0e5c7067-9cf0-445b-8374-4bf25484420c</field><field name="description_en">This is Steve Jobs 4 </field><field name="content_pos">This is text 4</field><field name="content"></field></doc></add>
```

*response for data insert*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response>
    <lst name="responseHeader">
        <int name="status">0</int>
        <int name="QTime">20</int>
    </lst>
</response>
```

*request for data select*

http://localhost:8983/solr/numberplate/select?q=*:*

*response for data select*

```
{
  "responseHeader": {
    "zkConnected": true,
    "status": 0,
    "QTime": 22,
    "params": {
      "q": "*:*"
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "numFound": 5,
    "start": 0,
    "maxScore": 1,
    "docs": [
      {
        "id": "0e5c7067-9cf0-445b-8374-4bf25484420c",
        "description_en": "This is Steve Jobs 4 ",
        "content_pos": [
          "This is text 4"
        ],
        "content": [
          ""
        ],
        "_version_": 1598004417210089500
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**Question**

What have I done wrong? Maybe NER in Solr 7.3 working in some other magical way or maybe I don't understand something correctly?

Comment: Have you ensured you match the implementation as specified here: https://lucene.apache.org/solr/7_3_0//solr-analysis-extras/org/apache/solr/update/processor/OpenNLPExtractNamedEntitiesUpdateProcessorFactory.html - also have you confirmed that your `.bin` model is actually working? (i.e. tested the model on some examples of the data you're indexing and confirmed that it does recognise the entities as expected?)

Comment: Hi, I have checked it and I have tested it but it is not working at all. At least if I assumed correctly how it SHOULD work.

Comment: I have added requests and responses but I as of it I don't see any named entity extraction.

Comment: Try a different source string, e.g. "This is Steve Jobs in white".  I don't know why, but the pre-built `en-ner-person.bin` model doesn't seem to extract names followed by numeric tokens.  If this is a problem, you should consider training a new model.

Comment: When I said tested it I meant have you tested your model outside of Solr? In just a small sample program or something? If it's not picking up the name when you indeed in Solr then you'll have to figure out if it's an issue with the model itself, or how you're using the model in Solr

Comment: @SteveRowe and @Jayce444 thanks for advise. But, yes. Model don't like numeric values... When I wrote _This is Steve Jobs write_ result in content field was -    ` ["","Steve Jobs"]` . Is this correct result of NER?

Comment: Yes, this is the correct result of NER, but note that the empty string value was in the original document, not added by NER.  You don't need to include the NER destination field in the initial (pre-NER) doc.

Comment: @SteveRowe  Ok, thanks a lot.